# use cmd to crfeate zip archive with password containing special characters

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, 7zip

I know this question has been asked several times, but all the different solutions don't work for me.

I'm trying to create a password protected zip Archive with 7z using cmd on Windows 10. The password may contain special characters.

The different proposed solutions I found were:

- put the passwort between single quotes
- put the password between double quotes
- escape the special character with backslash
- escape the special character with  the upward pipe.

So let's assume I want to encrypt the file with this password `abc_123"`.

I tried the following command with all the abovementioned alternatives, but none of these correctly recognized the password.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "test.zip" "FILE THAT SHOULD GO TO THE ARCHIVE" -pabc_123^"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "test.zip" "FILE THAT SHOULD GO TO THE ARCHIVE" -pabc_123\"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "test.zip" "FILE THAT SHOULD GO TO THE ARCHIVE" -p"abc_123^""
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "test.zip" "FILE THAT SHOULD GO TO THE ARCHIVE" -p'abc_123^"'
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?